# Transform date format in mySQL table and sort the result by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with inconsistent date formats. For example:

```
ID  date        name
1   01.02.2015  exampleA
2   12.13.2015  exampleB
3   1.11.2015   exampleC
```

Sometimes the date format is d.m.Y and sometimes the format is m.d.Y. I have created this SQL statement, which transforms the date column of the result in an uniform format:

```
SELECT IFNULL(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y'), '%d.%m.%Y'),
       DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m.%e.%Y'), '%e.%m.%Y')) AS date,
       Name,
       ID
FROM `exampleTable`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

But the result is not really ordered by date, because this column is treated like a number or something else, so that the order makes no sense.

- What should i do to get the required result?
- Is there a way to create a new column and write the date in an
  uniform format in my  table, so that i can delete the other date
  column?

Comment: Which is the column's datatype?

Comment: create a sqlfiddle or share sample data.

Comment: Too bad. Never store date/time in varchar columns.

Comment: I have importet a CSV file into the database and there was no option to choose the data type

Comment: It seems impossible to distinguish programmaticaly the format for the date like 02.03.2015 it can be both `%d.%m.%Y` and `%m.%e.%Y` it will give results in both cases though the results will be different. For alike varcahar inputs the information has been lost

Comment: @asd-tm you're right. I have not noticed this before. So my approach will not work...

Comment: Then if you are not against, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible to distinguish programmaticaly the format for the date like 02.03.2015 it can be both `%d.%m.%Y` and `%m.%e.%Y` it will give results in both cases though the results will be different. For alike varcahar inputs the information has been lost